# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.DataSet' to 'System.DateTime'

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I am trying to get system date through this method but is showing error saying :

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.DataSet' to 'System.DateTime'
```

Below is the method I am using. Any suggestions are appreciated. As why is this happening and how can I resolve it?

```
public DateTime GetLocalTime()
        {
            OracleBridge ob = new OracleBridge(_connStr);
            string sqlQuery = "select sysdate from dual";

            DateTime dt = new DateTime();
            try
            {

                dt = Convert.ToDateTime(ob.ExecuteScalar(sqlQuery, CommandType.Text));    //this line is giving error

            }
            catch (OracleException ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

            return dt;
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot convert, as the exception says, a `DataSet` type to a `DateTime`.

```
dt = ob.ExecuteQuery(sqlQuery, CommandType.Text);
```

That line is wrong. If you are expecting a only row result with a DateTime value, then you have to use the `ExecuteScalar` method and cast the result as DateTime:

```
dt = Convert.ToDateTime(yourOracleConnection.ExecuteScalar(sqlQuery, CommandType.Text)); //I assume you are using ADO.NET Library
```

If you are not expecting that result, you have to access to the specific row you are looking for, and then get the value as this:

```
dt = Convert.ToDateTime(ob.ExecuteQuery(sqlQuery, CommandType.Text).Tables[0].Rows[0]["YourColumnName"]); //You´ll have to check out where is the value you want and replace on the Rows[0]
```

Comment: I am expecting only one row result and when use the convert statement mentioned here it throws the following error:  cannot convert from 'System.Data.CommandType' to 'System.Data.OracleClient.OracleTransaction'

Comment: Are you trying ExecuteScalar? Do you have it implemented on your OracleBridge wrapper?. If so, post the code.

Comment: I all seems that you have a bad implementation of ExecuteScalar method

Comment: I have updated my code above with the latest that I have.

Comment: Post also OracleBridge.ExecuteScalar implementation

Comment: I cant find where it is impletmented I am fairly new to this

Comment: It worked fine I using command text which was not require and removed it and is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just one value that you are trying to retrieve then use `ExecuteScalar` method which will return an object.Convert it to datetime

```
    public DateTime GetLocalTime()
    {
        OracleBridge ob = new OracleBridge(_connStr);
        string sqlQuery = "select distinct sysdate from dual";

        DateTime dt = new DateTime();
        try
        {
            dt = Convert.ToDateTime(ob.ExecuteScalar(sqlQuery, CommandType.Text));
        }
        catch (OracleException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        return dt;
    }
```

Comment: @inquisitiveImind I am expecting only one row result and when use the convert statement mentioned here it throws the following error:  cannot convert from 'System.Data.CommandType' to 'System.Data.OracleClient.OracleTransaction'

Answer (score 0):

Answers provided already should be sufficant, in terms of syntax, if you throw the exception further all you actually need is

```
catch (OracleException)
{
   throw;
}
```